# Tween animation slow on Ice-Cream-Sandwich

Tags: android, animation, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've been playing around with tween animations for a while. In my latest project I'm declaring 4 rotate animations in xml like the folowing:

```
<rotate 
android:repeatMode="reverse"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="-7"
android:duration="1600"
android:pivotX="90%"
android:pivotY="63%">
</rotate>
</set>
```

And I'm aplying these 4 animations to 4 ImageViews. Everything worked perfect on Gingerbread but when i tested it on Ice-Cream-Sandwich i got horrible frame rates. What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at this site I recently found : http://laurencedawson.com/slow-animations-in-android
It may help you.
You could also tried to disable the hardware acceleration (which seems to be set to true by default on upper 3.x). Surprinsingly, I had the same problem with a laggy animation on ICS (that was working fine under 3.x), an android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in my manifest solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using setting the interpolator attribute to smooth out the animatoins `android:interpolator="@interpolator/accelerate_quad"`

You should place the interpolator .xml files in the `res\interpolator` folder of your project.

The files are located in `{android_sdk_location}\android-sdks\platforms\android-15\data\res\interpolator`

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it didn't help:( Everything still looks extremely choppy.